# Подключение к локальной БД mysql из Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask

Flask запушен из Docker и надо подключиться к БД, который стоит на сервера, а не в Docker.

```
    def __init__(self, app):
    self.mysql = MySQL()
    # MySQL configurations
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER']       = 'root'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD']   = '123'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB']         = 'medical'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST']       = 'localhost'
    app.config['MYSQL_PORT']                = '3306'
    try :
      self.mysql.init_app(app)
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

Вот сам код подключения. Но он не работает

Пишет 
**pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno -2] Name does not resolve)")**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Answer (score 0):

```
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST']       = 'localhost'
```

Т.е. подключение к хосту в контейнере. Укажи ip адресс, где установлен mysql.